# Tratando de generar un Widget con 2 filas en Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, programación-móvil

Quiero generar un Row con un icon, text  and text2...

La idea es hacer algo como esto

[image: idea]

pero no puedo hacerlo... Compartiré mi código y rezaré para que alguien me ayude :)

```
  Widget jobInfo(IconData icon, text, text2) {
return Row(children: [
  Icon(Icons.location_city_outlined),
  SizedBox(
    width: 5,
  ),
  Text(text),
  Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
    children: [
      Spacer(
        flex: 20,
      ),
      Text(text2)
    ],
  ),
]);}
```

Realmente agradeceré la ayuda!! ¡Qué tenga un buen fin de semana!

Comment: Hello Friend, your Post has a problem and is written in a different Language than the expected on the Site; I recommend that you translate it into Spanish.

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 0):

Lo que debías hacer es solo quitar ese `Row` adicional y agregar un `Spacer` para que ocupe todo el espacio disponible en la fila.

```dart
  Widget jobInfo(IconData icon, text, text2) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Icon(Icons.location_city_outlined),
        SizedBox(
          width: 5,
        ),
        Text(text),
        const Spacer(),
        Text(text2)
      ],
    );
  }
```